# Use same DTO library on client and server with asp.net webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, dto

Hello I have a (silverlight) class library containing plain DTO classes.
For this example "Person".

I have a ASP.NET Webservice (.asmx) that returns a List of Person.

Now on the consuming side (silverlight) I want to generate a client stub for the webservice.
This works ok, however, it generates a NEW Person class for me.. 
I want to reuse my existing DTO person class.

I tried to use Advanced->reuse types in referenced assemblies but until now to no avail....

Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this because Silverlight and .NET, while similar, use completely different runtimes and assemblies.  An assembly that is compiled for Silverlight cannot be used with the .NET CLR and vice-versa.

Comment: I used the silverlight dll in my asp.net website. That works fine..
So that is not the problem.